# Laplace transform of f(t/a)

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, laplace-method

If $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=F(s)$, what is the value of $\mathcal{L}\{f\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)\}$?

Well, I tried the problem and got  $$a \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s a u} \, f(u) \, du$$ using integration by parts. After this I don't know how to proceed. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are almost done. The change variables of variables $u=t/a$ gives $$\int^\infty_0 f(t/a) e^{-st}\,dt=a\int^\infty_0 f(u)e^{-sau}\,du=a F(as)$$ So, $(Lf_a)(s)=a(Lf)(as)$, where $f_a(t)=f(t/a)$.